# Do precompiled headers prevent inlining in g++ or clang++?

Tags: c++, gcc, build, clang, precompiled-headers

There is a way to enable precompiled headers in CMake that seem to work in `g++` and `clang++`:

```
target_precompile_headers(SRPlatform PUBLIC stdafx.h)
```

However, what happens to the inline functions defined in the headers, which are compiled into a precompiled header? Do they become non-inline?

Perhaps `g++` or `clang++` have link-time code generation, in that case it would be obvious that the precompiled headers don't prevent inlining, but I don't know of such feature in these compilers.

Comment: The generated file from the pre-compiled header contains the #defines, type definitions, the compiler parse tree etc not object code.  It's not until another module is compiled (that uses the pre-compiled header) that an object file is generated.  It's just a compiler time saving trick to only process common header files once and save the state of the compiler.

Comment: AFAIK there is no relationship at all between inlining and PCH. PCH is just a way of reducing the  workload and does not affect subsequent optimization in any way.

Comment: Unless you have hundreds (or rather, a few thousand) of headers, I am of the opinion that you are better off not using precompiled headers and saving yourself some headaches. The project has to be of a pretty significant size for PCHs to pay off in any meaningful way

Comment: @JesperJuhl, the project in focus has `813` files with `.h` extension, and more with other extensions like `.inc` and probably `.hpp`. Plus there are header-heavy libraries like Boost, etc. So with libraries the count of headers is indeed thousands.

Comment: BTW, if one of the header files is changed in a PCH, the PCH must be rebuilt (wasting build time).  To speed up build times, only use PCH on stable include files.

Comment: Please note `inline` keyword nowadays means "prevent multiple definition linker error". It doesn't mean that final code will be merged to the caller code. Optimizer will decide what to do with it. Precompiled headers have have nothing to this topic.

Comment: PCH should have no effect on compilation, the result should be exactly the same as if the headers were included normally, otherwise your compiler is buggy